# Camera automatically tilt when we start Recording

Tags: android

I am facing an issue in my app as when I start recording through camera it tilts to landscape which is not the requirement. The requirement is Recording should start according the the orientation of the Device. Means if device is in portrait mode then recording should start in Portrait and If camera in landscape mode then recording will atart in landscape.

But in our case when we click on start recording button then camera orientation will automaticaly changed to Landscape but Device still with the portrait orientation.

So, Please suggest any solution regarding that.

**Code:**

```
package com.irant.cameraApplication;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.media.MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Chronometer;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.irant.a1techno.CameraPlay;
import com.irant.a1techno.R;

/***
 *  TODO: 1. sound on/off
 *  2. resolution change
 * @author roman10
 *
 */

public class VideoCapture_New extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private SurfaceView prSurfaceView;
    private ImageButton prStartBtn, prFrontBackCamera;
    private Button prSettingsBtn;
    public String TAG = "IRANT";
    private boolean prRecordInProcess;
    private SurfaceHolder prSurfaceHolder;
    private Camera prCamera;
    private final String cVideoFilePath = "/sdcard/";
    Chronometer cm_VideoCapture;
    private Context prContext;
    public static boolean frontCamera= false;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        prContext = this.getApplicationContext();
        setContentView(R.layout.videocapture_new);
        Utils.createDirIfNotExist(cVideoFilePath);

        cm_VideoCapture = (Chronometer)findViewById(R.id.cm_VideoCapture);
        prSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface_camera);
        prStartBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.main_btn1);
        prFrontBackCamera = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btn_frontBackCamera);

       // prSettingsBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.main_btn2);
        prRecordInProcess = false;
        prStartBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            //@Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (prRecordInProcess == false) {
                    startRecording();
                    cm_VideoCapture.start();
                } else {
                    stopRecording();
                    cm_VideoCapture.stop();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(VideoCapture_New.this, CameraPlay.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });

        prFrontBackCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //prCamera = openFrontFacingCameraGingerbread();
                try{
            if(prCamera.getNumberOfCameras()==2)
            {
                if(frontCamera)
                {
                    frontCamera = false;
                    prCamera.stopPreview();
                    prMediaRecorder.release();
                    prMediaRecorder = null;
                    prCamera.release();
                    prCamera = null;
                }
                else
                {

                    frontCamera = true;
                    prCamera.stopPreview();
                    prMediaRecorder.release();
                    prMediaRecorder = null;
                    prCamera.release();
                    prCamera = null;
                }
                Intent intent = new Intent(VideoCapture_New.this, VideoCapture_New.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(VideoCapture_New.this, "Your device doesn't contain Front Camera.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
                }catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(VideoCapture_New.this, "Your device is not compatible for Front Camera.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

            }
        });

        prSurfaceHolder = prSurfaceView.getHolder();
        prSurfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        prSurfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        prMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    }

    private Camera openFrontFacingCameraGingerbread() 
    {
         Camera camera = null;

            // Look for front-facing camera, using the Gingerbread API.
            // Java reflection is used for backwards compatibility with pre-Gingerbread APIs.
            try {
                Class<?> cameraClass = Class.forName("android.hardware.Camera");
                Object cameraInfo = null;
                Field field = null;
                int cameraCount = 0;
                Method getNumberOfCamerasMethod = cameraClass.getMethod( "getNumberOfCameras" );
                if ( getNumberOfCamerasMethod != null ) {
                    cameraCount = (Integer) getNumberOfCamerasMethod.invoke( null, (Object[]) null );
                }
                Class<?> cameraInfoClass = Class.forName("android.hardware.Camera$CameraInfo");
                if ( cameraInfoClass != null ) {
                    cameraInfo = cameraInfoClass.newInstance();
                }
                if ( cameraInfo != null ) {
                    field = cameraInfo.getClass().getField( "facing" );
                }
                Method getCameraInfoMethod = cameraClass.getMethod( "getCameraInfo", Integer.TYPE, cameraInfoClass );
                if ( getCameraInfoMethod != null && cameraInfoClass != null && field != null ) {
                    for ( int camIdx = 0; camIdx < cameraCount; camIdx++ ) {
                        getCameraInfoMethod.invoke( null, camIdx, cameraInfo );
                        int facing = field.getInt( cameraInfo );
                        if ( facing == 1 ) { // Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT 
                            try {
                                Method cameraOpenMethod = cameraClass.getMethod( "open", Integer.TYPE );
                                if ( cameraOpenMethod != null ) {
                                    camera = (Camera) cameraOpenMethod.invoke( null, camIdx );
                                }
                            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                                Log.e(TAG, "Camera failed to open: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                                camera= prCamera;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            // Ignore the bevy of checked exceptions the Java Reflection API throws - if it fails, who cares.
            catch ( ClassNotFoundException e        ) {Log.e(TAG, "ClassNotFoundException" + e.getLocalizedMessage());}
            catch ( NoSuchMethodException e         ) {Log.e(TAG, "NoSuchMethodException" + e.getLocalizedMessage());}
            catch ( NoSuchFieldException e          ) {Log.e(TAG, "NoSuchFieldException" + e.getLocalizedMessage());}
            catch ( IllegalAccessException e        ) {Log.e(TAG, "IllegalAccessException" + e.getLocalizedMessage());}
            catch ( InvocationTargetException e     ) {Log.e(TAG, "InvocationTargetException" + e.getLocalizedMessage());}
            catch ( InstantiationException e        ) {Log.e(TAG, "InstantiationException" + e.getLocalizedMessage());}
            catch ( SecurityException e             ) {Log.e(TAG, "SecurityException" + e.getLocalizedMessage());}
            catch ( NullPointerException e             ) {Log.e(TAG, "NullPointerException" + e.getLocalizedMessage());}

            if ( camera == null ) {
                // Try using the pre-Gingerbread APIs to open the camera.
                try {
                    camera = Camera.open();
                } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Camera failed to open: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                }
            }

            return camera;
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder _holder, int _format, int _width, int _height) {
        Camera.Parameters lParam = prCamera.getParameters();

        prCamera.setParameters(lParam);
        try {
            prCamera.setPreviewDisplay(_holder);
            prCamera.startPreview();
            //prPreviewRunning = true;
        } catch (IOException _le) {
            _le.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
        if(frontCamera == false)
        {
        prCamera = Camera.open();
        if (prCamera == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), "Camera is not available!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
        }
        else if(frontCamera == true)
        {
            try{
         int cameraCount = 0;
            Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
            cameraCount = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
            for ( int camIdx = 0; camIdx < cameraCount; camIdx++ ) {
                Camera.getCameraInfo( camIdx, cameraInfo );
                if ( cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT  ) {
                    try {
                        prCamera = Camera.open( camIdx );
                    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                        Log.i("Camera failed to open: ",e.getLocalizedMessage());
                    }
                }
            }
            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                Toast.makeText(VideoCapture_New.this, "Your Device doesn't compatible for Fron Camera.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
        try {
            if (prRecordInProcess) {
                stopRecording();
            } else {
                prCamera.stopPreview();
            }
            prMediaRecorder.release();
            prMediaRecorder = null;
            prCamera.release();
            prCamera = null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    private MediaRecorder prMediaRecorder;
    private final int cMaxRecordDurationInMs = 30000;
    private final long cMaxFileSizeInBytes = 5000000;
    private final int cFrameRate = 20;
    private File prRecordedFile;

    private void updateEncodingOptions() {
        if (prRecordInProcess) {
            stopRecording();
            startRecording();
            Toast.makeText(prContext, "Recording restarted with new options!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(prContext, "Recording options updated!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private boolean startRecording() {
        prCamera.stopPreview();
        try {
            prCamera.unlock();
            prMediaRecorder.setCamera(prCamera);

            prMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

            String lVideoFileFullPath=".mp4";
            prMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
            String lDisplayMsg = "Current container format: ";
            prMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(VideoEncoder.H263);


            lDisplayMsg += "Current encoding format: ";

            lVideoFileFullPath = cVideoFilePath + "myvideo" + lVideoFileFullPath;
            //prMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(360);
            prMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(176, 144); 
            prMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(12);
            prRecordedFile = new File(lVideoFileFullPath);
            prMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(prRecordedFile.getPath());


            prMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(cFrameRate);
            prMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(prSurfaceHolder.getSurface());
            prMediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(cMaxRecordDurationInMs);
            prMediaRecorder.setMaxFileSize(cMaxFileSizeInBytes);
            //prepare for capturing
            //state: DataSourceConfigured => prepared
            prMediaRecorder.prepare();
            //start recording
            //state: prepared => recording
            prMediaRecorder.start();
            //prStartBtn.setText("Stop");
            prRecordInProcess = true;
            return true;
        } catch (IOException _le) {
            _le.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

    private void stopRecording() {
        prMediaRecorder.stop();
        prMediaRecorder.reset();
        try {
            prCamera.reconnect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //prStartBtn.setText("Start");
        prRecordInProcess = false;
        prCamera.startPreview();
    }

    private static final int REQUEST_DECODING_OPTIONS = 0;
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_DECODING_OPTIONS:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                updateEncodingOptions();
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and this little snipped fixed it

```
        Camera.CameraInfo info = new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
        Camera.getCameraInfo(0, info);
        int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
        int degrees = 0;
        switch (rotation) {
            case Surface.ROTATION_0: degrees = 0; break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_90: degrees = 90; break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_180: degrees = 180; break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_270: degrees = 270; break;
        }

        int result;
        if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
            result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
            result = (360 - result) % 360;  // compensate the mirror
        } else {  // back-facing
            result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
        }

        this.mRotation = result;

        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(result);
```

I am not sure why it doesn't start at the current phone orientation but I am sure this fixes it.

Comment: Hello Ruuhkis, Please help me out for one more thing is, when we play the recorded video then its orientation get changed. How it will resolve?

Comment: I am pretty sure you have to set the orientation of the video when saving to gallery as you have to do with images. I didn't yet find a way to do that. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.html#ORIENTATION is for images